# How to convert probabilistic pairwise rankings to _probabilistic_ global ranking

Tags: machine-learning, probability, ranking

I have a set of items (say, A, B and C) and all possible pairwise rankings, in the form of probabilities. For example, `P(item A > item B) = 0.6`.

How do you convert into a global *probabilistic* ranking, such that you have a probability for each combination?

For example:

```
P(A > B > C) = ...
P(A > C > B) = ...
P(B > A > C) = ...
```

etc. Is this problem solved or attacked successfully?

Comment: Hey @Nucular, are the `P(A>B)`s here independent or are they conditionally independent given some distribution? Would `P(A>B) = 1 - P(B>A)`, assuming both are present, and could `P(C>A) > P(A>B)P(B>C)`?

Comment: `P(A>B) = 1 - P(B>A)` - most certainly; `P(C>A) > P(A>B)P(B>C)` - that would indicate an inconsistency, so no